# Places api for Apple Maps

Tags: ios6, apple-maps

We have google api list out the places.i.e:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=Amoeba&types=establishment&location=37.76999,-122.44696&radius=500&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

Using this we get the list of places.

But My question is:How to get the list of places using Apple Maps in iOS 6.1(That means with out using google Api).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you want to know is how to get a list of interesting locations / places from the maps api. I believe what you want is not provided. IMHO you will always have to refer to a specific server such as Google / Yelp / ... to give you a list of interesting places. iOS6 Maps API only provides a means how to present those on the device.

Hope it helps,
EL